# Destructively reverse every cons node in an s-expression

Tags: lisp, s-expression, cons

Any ideas how to go about this?  I am trying to not create any new nodes.

Answer (score 3):

Call [nreverse](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/fun_reversecm_nreverse.html).

Comment: If it's not homework, that's the right answer (just make sure to assign the result to something, like (setf foo-prime (nreverse foo))).  If it's homework, I'd rather the questioner said so.

Answer (score 1):

Draw a standard cons-cell diagram of what a list with 5 elements or so looks like.  That should give you a big clue right there.

Don't forget to keep a reference to the last cell in the list, which will be your new list head when done.